# Why the move constructor doesn't get invoked in this case?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, icc

I was following this article [Ten C++11 Features Every C++ Developer Should Use](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570638/Ten-Cplusplus-Features-Every-Cplusplus-Developer) and added some basic tracing to the code of the [Move semantics](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570638/Ten-Cplusplus-Features-Every-Cplusplus-Developer#movesemantics) example and see that the move constructor is never invoked and wonder just why. I have tried with both compilers GNU 4.6.3 and Intel 15.0.0 and the result is the same.

I compile it like this:

```
# using Intel compiler
icpc -Wall -g -Wno-shadow -std=c++0x -o showcase ./showcase.cpp

# using gnu g++ compiler
g++ -Wall -g -Wno-shadow -std=gnu++0x -o showcase ./showcase.cpp
```

This is the output I get where the move constructor is not invoked when it should at line 133:

```
instantiating b1 ...
Buffer() default constructor invoked 
my name is: 
instantiating b2 ...
Buffer(const std::string& name, size_t size) constructor invoked 
my name is: buf2
instantiating b3 ...
Buffer(const Buffer& copy) copy constructor invoked 
my name is: buf2
instantiating b4 ...
Buffer(const std::string& name, size_t size) constructor invoked 
my name is: buf64
moving getBuffer<int>("buf5") to b1 ...
Buffer(const std::string& name, size_t size) constructor invoked 
Buffer& operator=(Buffer&& temp) move assignment operator invoked
my name is: buf5
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//============================================================================
// Classes
//============================================================================

template <typename T>
class Buffer 
{
   std::string          _name;
   size_t               _size;
   std::unique_ptr<T[]> _buffer;

public:
   // default constructor
   Buffer():
      _size(16),
      _buffer(new T[16]) {
      cout << "Buffer() default constructor invoked " << endl;
   }

   // constructor
   Buffer(const std::string& name, size_t size):
      _name(name),
      _size(size),
      _buffer(new T[size]) {
      cout << "Buffer(const std::string& name, size_t size) constructor invoked " << endl;
   }

   // copy constructor
   Buffer(const Buffer& copy):
      _name(copy._name),
      _size(copy._size),
      _buffer(new T[copy._size])
   {
      cout << "Buffer(const Buffer& copy) copy constructor invoked " << endl;
      T* source = copy._buffer.get();
      T* dest = _buffer.get();
      std::copy(source, source + copy._size, dest);
   }

   void print_name() const {
        cout << "my name is: " << _name << endl;
   }

   // copy assignment operator
   Buffer& operator=(const Buffer& copy)
   {
      cout << "Buffer& operator=(const Buffer& copy) assignment operator invoked " << endl;
      if(this != &copy)
      {
         _name = copy._name;

         if(_size != copy._size)
         {
            _buffer = nullptr;
            _size = copy._size;
            _buffer = _size > 0 ? new T[_size] : nullptr;
         }

         T* source = copy._buffer.get();
         T* dest = _buffer.get();
         std::copy(source, source + copy._size, dest);
      }

      return *this;
   }

   // move constructor
   Buffer(Buffer&& temp):
      _name(std::move(temp._name)),
      _size(temp._size),
      _buffer(std::move(temp._buffer))
   {
      cout << "Buffer(Buffer&& temp) move constructor invoked" << endl;
      temp._buffer = nullptr;
      temp._size = 0;
   }

   // move assignment operator
   Buffer& operator=(Buffer&& temp)
   {
      cout << "Buffer& operator=(Buffer&& temp) move assignment operator invoked" << endl;
      assert(this != &temp); // assert if this is not a temporary

      _buffer = nullptr;
      _size = temp._size;
      _buffer = std::move(temp._buffer);

      _name = std::move(temp._name);

      temp._buffer = nullptr;
      temp._size = 0;

      return *this;
   }
};

template <typename T>
Buffer<T> getBuffer(const std::string& name) {
   Buffer<T> b(name, 128);
   return b;
}

//============================================================================
// Main
//============================================================================

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "**************** move semantics" << endl;
    cout << "instantiating b1 ..." << endl;
    Buffer<int> b1;
    b1.print_name();
    cout << "instantiating b2 ..." << endl;
    Buffer<int> b2("buf2", 64);
    b2.print_name();
    cout << "instantiating b3 ..." << endl;
    Buffer<int> b3 = b2;
    b3.print_name();
    cout << "instantiating b4 by moving from a temp object ..." << endl;
    Buffer<int> b4 = getBuffer<int>("buf64"); // Buffer<int>("buf4", 64);
    b4.print_name();
    cout << "moving getBuffer<int>(\"buf5\") to b1 ..." << endl;
    b1 = getBuffer<int>("buf5");
    b1.print_name();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I guess you don't see move due to copy-elision that took place

Comment: for GCC use `-fno-elide-constructors` command line option

Comment: Yes, using the command line option `-fno-elide-constructors` solves the issue. I have to find the same for the icpc compiler ...

Comment: You could have reduced this program significantly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The move assignment operator is correctly invoked.

For the case where you expected a move construction, the `b4`, you're getting return value optimization (RVO) where the result object is directly constructed in caller-provided storage. Whether this happens depends on the compiler and options: it's permitted but not required. I.e. it's a Quality of Implementation issue.

---

Note that it's not a good idea to use e.g. `-fno-elide-constructors` to avoid this. RVO is much more efficient than ordinary construction plus move construction. It has to be, since it's less.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was just worried that RVO wasn't happening. Is there a way to know whether it is happening other than using this no-elide-constructor?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: With g++ use `-S` to generate assembly. On PC platform perhaps use `-masm=intel`, if you prefer Intel syntax (I do ). Search for relevant names. An alternative (still for g++) is to use debugger in e.g. Code::Blocks.

Comment: No, you are not the only person. I refuse to read assembly to find out whether something is working :)

Answer (score 2):

The elision of copy/move operations is allowed in some cases. Though the copy or move constructors shall be acceptable. For example if you will set the private access control for the move constructor in your class then the compiler will issue an error at least for this statement

```
Buffer<int> b4 = getBuffer<int>("buf64");
```

where if the elision would not be allowed then the move constructor would be called.